# Plain list with heading in between into dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a situation like below:

```
Heading 1
item 1
item 2
Heading 2
item 1
Heading 3
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

This is a plain list of text, I need to convert this into a dictionary in python as,

```
{
 Heading 1: [item 1, item 2], 
 Heading 2: [item 1], 
 Heading 3: [item 1, item 2, item 3]
}
```

Any item to achieve this? I am working with python and pandas specially.

Comment: What is a "plain list of text," exactly?

Comment: I have given an example on top part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}
for line in open('text.file'):
    if line.split()[0] == "Heading": 
        current = line
        dictionary[line] = []
        continue
    dictionary[current].append(line)
```

This will fail if the first line in the file isn't a heading, but you expect this is so that's good. You save the current heading, and continue to append the items to the current cell in the dict.

Comment: Thank you kabanus, is there any why to create a data.frame repeating the keys in one column. It would be more helpful.

Comment: If you accept answers too quickly don't expect other answers to come in